# Line graph automatically connects with other collection in DynamicDataDisplay WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, dynamic-data-display

In my project, i have to display multiple line graphs dynamically.

If i bind more than one dynamic collection to my D3 line graph, every collection end point gets automatically connects with next collection first point. Please help me to differentiate line graphs.

[image]

Comment: can you show your code?

Comment: Hai foggy finder, i can't add my code through this command. How can i show my entire code to u?

Comment: may you create github repo?

Comment: Dear Foggy, i have created github with the title "Line Graph D3" . Link "https://gist.github.com/bala150886/561db19265aea69bfba3b6b6382a3e31"